# Home key will not open last activity

Tags: android, android-intent

When i press Home key and then application Icon then it will show me last activity but it will always start the first activity that is from main->first activity.Where main is the launch activity.But if i restart the application then it will work perfectly.So can anybody know why it will work after restart and not at starting? 
My Application flow is like this way.Application class->Main activity->Tab activity with5 tabs and each tab open separete activity.
**edit**
  I restart application like this way: in eclipse again run the application and in phone from settings->application->manage applications->myapplication->force close.Then click on application icon.
 Sipdroid is launch activity and welcome is first activity which has 5 tabs.

This is my [menifest.xml file](http://pastie.org/4198331)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved by just removing the `android:launchmode="SingleInstance"` tag from manifest file.